# Order by commonness of words: Sentence matching

Tags: python, nlp, data-science-model

I'm trying to compare two sentences which might or might not be about the same theme (product). I've tried a few metrics like cosine similarity, distance etc. but the results are not very impressive. I figure, if I can see the type of words that are getting matched (common words vs rare words), I can try to do something to better tailor the logic as per the use case. Does Python have such a library?

Suppose I'm trying to compare **A** and **B** in the below example. There are several words which don't provide conclusive evidence that they are the same even if they match, but there are certain words (like Mochi, Squishy) which may be better explanators.

Eg.
**A**:
Kawaii Squishies, Mochi Squishy Toys for Kids Party Favors, Mini Stress Relief Toys for Halloween Christmas Easter Party Favors, Birthday Gifts, Classroom Prizes, Goodie Bag

**B**:
I highly recommend these for anyone with anxiety, depression, adhd, trouble focusing, stress, ect. They are called mochi squishy toys and are wonderful to distract you from stress, or just to get your frustration out.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are looking for a term-weighing scheme. I'd try to address this using TF-IDF which is the most popular term weighing scheme today.

Here's a brief recap of TF-IDF from wiki:

> In information retrieval, tf–idf, TF*IDF, or TFIDF, short for term frequency–inverse document frequency, is a numerical statistic that is intended to reflect how important a word is to a document in a collection or corpus.[1] It is often used as a weighting factor in searches of information retrieval, text mining, and user modeling. The tf–idf value increases proportionally to the number of times a word appears in the document and is offset by the number of documents in the corpus that contain the word, which helps to adjust for the fact that some words appear more frequently in general. tf–idf is one of the most popular term-weighting schemes today

As your use-case is different from a standard document search, I'd try a modified ranking method as listed below:

1. Find all the common words between **A** and **B**, let's say there are *n* such words.
2. Calculate TF-IDF score for all common words individually for **A** and **B** and add them to have *n* scores. You will need to use whole of your text corpus for this.
3. Define a parameter k (1,2,3 etc), which will act as cut-off to the number of common words used in ranking.
4. Take the sum total of TF-IDF of the top k common words and apply thresholding on it to build a binary 'relevant', 'irrelevant' classification.

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying to use the gensim library for TF-IDF. The only problem is that corpus is vastly different for every few datapoints. Does python have any ready made corpus for English language? That'll help avoid preparing a separate corpus for each set.

Comment: There are a number of open source NLP oriented text datasets. The easiest ones are provided by python ‘nltk’ package.